# Jakob Böhme - influence

Tags: mysticism

Which denominations apart from Quakerism, if any other, were influenced by the teachings of German Protestant mystic Jakob Böhme?

Comment: Quakers have had a lot of influence on other groups. Are you interested in the trickle down effect or only those he had direct interaction with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both, direct and indirect influences.

Comment: Someone is going to write a book to answer this question.

Comment: Some guidance on the topic would suffice..

Comment: Agree with Freemason here, this is a book topic, not an SE question, you'll need to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

[His Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_B%C3%B6hme) lists some people he influenced:

> Pierre Poiret, John Pordage, William Law, Louis Claude de Saint-Martin, William Blake, Hegel, Schopenhauer, Friedrich Wilhelm Joseph Schelling, Julius Evola

Going through those it seems like area of influence was mostly Enlightenment philosophers, Theosophists, and liberal mainline Protestants. One that stands out is John Pordage, who founded the [Philadelphians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphians).

> The Philadelphians [...] were a Protestant 17th century religious group in England. They were organized around John Pordage (1607–1681), an Anglican priest from Bradfield, Berkshire [...] Pordage was attracted to the ideas of Jakob Böhme, a Lutheran theosophist and Christian mystic.

Comment: Can you please copy and edit some of the relevant material in your post? If the link should be broken, we will no longer have the benefit of your answer.